# How to supply some security access?

Tags: python, email, html-email

Hello I have this code:

```
username = input("Target Mail: ")
password = input("Password: ")

server=e.connect("imap.gmail.com",username,password)
server.listids()
email=server.mail(server.listids()[0])

print("\n<|From|> " + email.from_addr + " <|From|>")
print("<|Title|> " + email.title + " <|Title|>\n")
print("\n<|Title|> MESSAGES <|Title|>\n")
print(email.body)
```

but problem is it doesn't work if i don't enable less secure app access on my google account's settings.

[image]

So how can I run my code without enable this? Cause it's really annoying.

Comment: You need to work with the Google API documentation; it's their interface, so they get to set the security standards.

Comment: @Prune Can I fix this by editing the code? Thanks

Comment: Question on Stack Overflow must be in English, and that includes error messages (or screenshots of them).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to send an email from a gmail account, you would want to register your app and go through an oauth flow. Documentation for getting started with that is here:

oauth flow here:

https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python

email example through gmail python module/package here:

https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/sending

IMAP is a mail protocol which is less secure than a properly setup OAUTH flow. That is why you are receiving the message and forced configuration for it to work.